# getting alpha by subtracting two images with different backgrounds

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I am using a program what can render color images but only **without alpha information**. I would like to **get alpha information** from those images by using two and subtracting them. I can set the background to different colors.

My idea is that if I **render an image with black background** and an other **one with white**, then I can **subtract those images** from each other and **get an alpha channel**. But it is just a theory, I don't know how to do it in practise and that if there are any standard methods / algorithms for extracting alpha information out of two images by subtracting them from each other.

I would like to use a **command line program** (or a very easy to use **library in C++**) to do this processing. I have used convert.exe from ImageMagick before, but I have never used the other utilities in ImageMagick.

Is there anyone who can recommend me a way how to do it in practise? What I am looking for is some kind of a command line solution or a C++ library with easy to understand example files what can do this.

**Update**:
My backgrounds are computer generated, solid colors. So I can set it to 0,0,0 black. Here is an example.

[image: sample image]

Comment: It doesn't sound like you want an alpha channel, which can specify partially transparent areas. It sounds like you want a pixel mask for either opaque or fully transparent areas. If so, you just choose a background color and then any pixels that match it are transparent. Pixels that don't are opaque. The technique with black and white is used to blit-ROP render with transparency.

Comment: What I would like is a 8-bit grayscale channel based on the transparency. Isn't it possible using two images?

Comment: Again, not sure what you mean by "transparency".  Or even how you mean "grayscale" here.  Do you mean you want a map of which pixels are transparent and which are opqaue?  Do you mean that you want to convert a color image to grayscale?  Those two things are mutually exclusive concepts so I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: You seem to be looking for "Triangulation Matting" I wrote an implementation for a course in University... but I can't find it... If I can remember how it works I'll try to work out how to make ImageMagick do the computation. Although you do need 4 images to make it work.. (2 different backgrounds, then each background with and without the object)

Comment: My background is totally black, solid color. It is a computer generated image.

Comment: I'm curious why you have a computer generated image, but the program can't generate any transparency. Is it just a file format limitation?

Comment: It is a custom program, for volumetric visualization. The program uses OpenGL to render images and at the moment it cannot render images bigger than the screen size if alpha transparency is used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#known_bgnd) might be good enough if your object differs enough from the background but [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/masking/#two_background) looks like it might be **exactly** what you asked for

EDIT: the second one ends up with this command line (replace the stuff in <> with your images)

```
  convert <image1> <image2> -alpha off \
          \( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite \
             -separate -evaluate-sequence max -auto-level -negate \) \
          \( -clone 0,2 -fx "v==0?0:u/v-u.p{0,0}/v+u.p{0,0}" \) \
          -delete 0,1 +swap -compose Copy_Opacity -composite \
          <output>
```

You'll need to use a format that supports alpha on the output, but that's probably what you want anyway. (NOTE: I have not actually tried this for myself so it might not work with the latest imagemagick versions since I don't think that documentation is always up to date)

Or, if you actually just use pure black and white you can do it like this:

```
  convert <image1> <image2> -alpha off \
          \( -clone 0,1 -compose difference -composite -negate \) \
          \( -clone 0,2 +swap -compose divide -composite \) \
          -delete 0,1 +swap -compose Copy_Opacity -composite \
          <output>
```

Comment: That post is a great find. Not only does it give the answer, but it explains how it works step by step.

Comment: @Spudd86: My backgrounds are computer generated, solid colors. So I can set it to 0,0,0 black. I have uploaded an example image. Do you think in that case I can use the second version?

Comment: @zsero, I'd use the second version for sure. It looks custom-made for your problem.

Comment: @zsero Yes, Mark is right use the second one if you can do 0,0,0 and 1,1,1 as your two backgrounds